# How to make angular typescript function works inside <a> html element

Tags: angular

I want to make the `comment()` function inside this element works.

```
<a routerLink="/comment" ng-click="comment()">comment</a>
```

function inside the typescript

```
 comment(){console.log("clicked")}
```

Yes, I can go to the `/comment` component page but no log appears in the console so I assume the function is not called.

Is it possible to make the function work?

or even use that function to pass value?

If not is there any way to work around it?

Comment: what angular version do you use?

Comment: ng7-pre version ?

Comment: Is it angularjs? Did you try it: ng-click="comment"?

Comment: it is a function in a typescript in a component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the click event `<a routerLink="/comment" (click)="comment()">comment</a>`

Comment: yeah it works, I wonder why it didn't compile last time, I saw this method in another post a few years ago, I thought it is outdated, but now it works, it must be I forget to delete the ) which the software auto-generated, Welp I guess this is a duplicated post then  ... sorry .... stack overflow ....

Comment: @ACFake your original code worked or the solution provided here?

Comment: your solution provided here works, my original code didn't work.

Comment: ok thanks for clarifying, please consider accepting answer if the problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

Try using it as below, it works:

```
 <a routerLink="/comment" (click)="comment()">comment</a>
```

You define an event binding by wrapping the event between (), and calling a method.

You can refer difference between event binding in AngularJS and Angular here:
[Event binding in different versions of Angular](https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference#ng-click)